# Comments can be entered using the first input box only. They don't work for the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery

After you run the html for the first time, comment the lines that store the local storage values. Then enter some value in the comment box and press enter. The comments can be entered for the first item in the list. If you try to do the same for the next item, they don't work. :( Comments can't be entered anywhere apart from the first box.

JSBin - http://jsbin.com/dosicuteku/2/

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. I thought that posting a link would make the question easier to read. I will remember this tip though. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you are reading the value of the `input` box, you are using `document.querySelector('.commentsBox').value` to read the value of the `input` element on which the `keyup` has happened, but here the problem is `document.querySelector('.commentsBox')` will always return the value of the first element with the class `commentsBox`, so if there are more than 1 element then it will always return the first element not the element where the keypress has happened.

In your case `this` inside the `keyup` event refer to the element which raised the event so you can simply use `this.value` to get the value of the current element. So change the following lines

```
//var comVal = document.querySelector('.commentsBox').value;
var comVal = this.value;
//....
//text = document.querySelector('.commentsBox').value;
text = this.value;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9omwdkw6/)